# Image has padding/margin when they have been set to 0

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am running into a very annoying problem. My images in my slider have a padding or margin set to them for some reason. I have applied 0 margin and padding and have added `position: absolute;` and `top: 0;` and this does nothing to help get rid of this whitespace.

```
<div class="slider">
     <div class="slide"><img src="http://realtorcatch.com/images/subway2.jpg">
     <span>My Text for "FooBar1"!</span></div>
     <div class="slide"><img src="http://realtorcatch.com/images/beach2.jpg">
     <span>My Text for "FooBar2"!</span></div>
     <div class="slide"><img src="http://realtorcatch.com/images/space2.jpg">
     <span>My Text for "FooBar3"!</span></div>
  </div>
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.slider {margin: 0; padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 0;}
.slide {position: absolute; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
.slide img {display: block; max-width: 100%;}
.slide span {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 50%; text-align: center; width: 100%; font-size: 2em; color: white;}
.bx-controls.bx-has-controls-direction.bx-has-pager {margin-top: -50px;}
```

You can see a real life example here:

http://jsbin.com/gizebukisi/edit?html,css,js,output

Can anyone tell why there is whitespace?

Comment: Where do you see the whitespace? At the bottom?

Comment: Around the top, right and left areas of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your jsbin this is not a white space this a white border you need to remove it with the following css

```
.bx-wrapper{border: 0}
```

I update your [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/miqiquqobu/1/edit?html,css,js,output) take a look here

Comment: That gets rid of the margins, but then it throws my pager out of the slider div? Then it makes a shaded like border line at the bottom?

Comment: I don't get why `.bx-wrapper {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` aren't taking. I don't even see it in the console when I check.

Comment: margin and padding are not usefull here beceause the white space is comming from the border try `.bx-wrapper{border-left: 0; border-right: 0}`

Comment: @Becky The shaded line apprears to be a `box-shadow` applied to `bx-wrapper`. remove it by `.bx-wrapper{box-shadow:none;}`

Comment: @Becky Also your slide images are not the same height. It may cause problems as the slider plugin dynamically calculates the height of the container using the first image. So if consecutive slides are shorter you could see additional whitespace.

Comment: The issue with having only the `.bx_wrapper{border: 0;}` is it kicks the pager (three circles) out from the image for some reason. Doing border-top-right-left makes the margins go away, but my problem with the margin is this: `margin: 0 auto 60px;`....It adds 60px's to the bottom. I would rather have `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @VictorLevin +1 yes your image are not the same height, fix them and  make your `.bx-pager{bottom: 10px}` see my update on jsbin http://jsbin.com/tetebosozo/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Gotcha on the images. Thanks. So, it looks like it makes the margins based on the largest image, not the first. That made it pretty much perfect with adding in the `box shadow: none;`